# C++ i18n Solutions

Tags: c++, internationalization

After playing with gettext and finding I wasn't able to manually load .mo files, and having to have a directory structure for projects I ship with that seemed unnecessary, I was wondering if there were any other i18n libraries.

So I guess my question is, are there simple lookup tables? I've seen OpenTTD do something like I want to do, but haven't investigated it yet as I'd rather use something that I can blame other people for, rather than myself.

Comment: Linux. Ideally it'd be cross platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boost.Locale has recently been accepted into Boost and should be available in the next release. It is currently available on the SVN in /trunk to play with (and by now it's probably been merged to /release too, assuming the branch is open again).

http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/boost_locale/html/index.html

Comment: Boost uses gettext for message translating. What a mess.

Comment: Ahaha, I take that back. I was frustrated of the file structure, but Boost.Locale allows you to specify your own loaders.

Answer (score 2):

There is some support of i18n in [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/i18n), but I have not tried it myself.